# How to find all words in a sentence between two charterers using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract all the works in a sentence that exists between two Set of words using regex

```
var sentence = "i would like to extract $#word1#$ ,$#word2#$ and $#word3#$"
/\$\#(.*?)\#\$/g.exec(sentence);
```

output is

```
["$#word1#$", "word1"]
```

Expected output is

```
['word1','word2','word3']
```

Comment: Can you share what you tried?

Answer (score -1):

I tried to use `match` function, but I've got the array( ["$#word1#$", "$#word2#$", "$#word3#$"])

So, for your case I used function `replace` function. Here is code:

```
const subStrings = [];
sentence.replace(/\$\#(.+?)\#\$/g, (str, word) => subStrings.push(word));

console.log(subStrings);
```

Output `subStrings`: `['word1','word2','word3']`

Additional information:
If you want to use `exec` function you should take a look at this example:

```
var regex1 = RegExp('foo*','g');
var str1 = 'table football, foosball';
var array1;

while ((array1 = regex1.exec(str1)) !== null) {
  console.log(`Found ${array1[0]}. Next starts at ${regex1.lastIndex}.`);
  // expected output: "Found foo. Next starts at 9."
  // expected output: "Found foo. Next starts at 19."
}
```

More information about `replace` function:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

More information about `exec` function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec